# Magento get formatted product URL

Tags: api, magento

I'm trying to get the formatting product url from a Magento product collection.

So I want `https://www.myshop.co.uk/red-bouncy-ball.html`

Specifically the `red-bouncy-ball` part.

I've tried this method:

```
$categoryId = $product->getCategoryIds();
$url = $product->setCategoryId($categoryId)->getProductUrl();
```

Which gives me:

```
https://www.myshop.co.uk/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/100/
```

and just

```
$product->getProductUrl()
```

which does the same.

Comment: you should join url_rewrites table with your collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you simply looking for the 'red-bouncy-ball' part of the url?

If so then...

```
$product->getData('url_key');
```

When initialising your collection you will need to add the url_key to the select statement...

addAttributeToSelect('url_key')

Comment: Yes, I want the url formatted product name . ie. 'red-bouncy-ball'. Using '$product->getData('url_key');' returns an empty string.

Comment: You need to add yhe url_key to the select  when initialising the collection.  Have updated the answer for you